# php login without mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having this code at the top of my index.php

```
<?php
include("security.php");
?>
```

and here is the security.php

```
 <?php
session_start();

$user["admin"] = "123";

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
    echo '<h1>Login</h1>';
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            echo '<span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">Please fill in all fields!</span>';
        }
        elseif ($user[$_POST['username']] != $_POST['password'])
        {
            echo '<span style="color:red; font-weight: bold">Your username/password is wrong!</span>';
        }
        else
        {
            header("Refresh: 1");
            $_SESSION['ingelogd'] = true;
            echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight: bold">You are now logged in!</span>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit('You need to log-in to view this page.<br /><br />
        <form method="POST" action=""><p>
        Username:<br />
        <input type="text" name="username" /><br /><br />
        Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> <input type="reset" value="Empty fields" />
        </form>');
    }
}
?>
```

but the fact is when I login using admin and pass it logs in but after some time it redirects me back to the login page..

please tell me how to stay at index.php after login..

Comment: "after some time"? How much time? You've got a refresh header in the above code, but it's only for 1 second...

Comment: You check for `logged_in`, but set it later in dutch (`ingelogd`), so your `logged_in` is never set, hence after the reload you're still not seen as logged in. Next time, try some debugging first ;)

Answer (score 2):

chek your following code:

**wrong**:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
```

**should be**:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['ingelogd']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting session     `$_SESSION['ingelogd']` to true

```
header("Refresh: 1");
$_SESSION['ingelogd'] = true;
echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight: bold">You are now logged in!</span>';
```

But your are checking  `$_SESSION['logged_in']` which is not set. 
So I think changing either of one will fix your problem